Angular momentum conservation and isotropy of space
If we consider a spin-less particle at some state $|\psi\rangle$ belonging to the state space $\mathcal{H}_r$ then the following holds true:
Invariance of the quantum mechanical system under rotation means that the expectation value of the Hamiltonian operator that describes the quantum mechanical system is the same after the rotation as it was before the rotation.
Can someone describe me a case where a rotation of the frame of reference (passive rotation) or of the position vector, which would imply a rotation of the system under consideration (active rotation) makes the above statement false?
Edit - begin:
I don't know if this makes sense but can't it happen that before the rotation no forces act on the system and the hamiltonian has a certain value, then, while a rotation occurs, a force, unrelated to the rotation causes the hamiltonian to change, so after the rotation we have a different value for it. And it would look like, as if it's the rotation that caused this change of the hamiltonian, when in fact it wasn't because of it. Am I wrong for thinking this?
Edit-end
Additionally, if we have:
$|\psi'\rangle=R|\psi\rangle$
$\vec r'=R\vec r$
Then from the above statement the following is true:
$\langle \psi'|H|\psi'\rangle=\langle \psi|R^\dagger H R|\psi'\rangle=\langle \psi|H|\psi\rangle$
$H=R^\dagger H R \rightarrow [H,\vec L]=0$.
Another statement is made:
The conservation of orbital angular momentum is therefore associated with the isotropy of space (all directions are equal), i.e. the invariance of the closed physical system under rotations.
I don't really understand this statement. How is the conservation of angular momentum associated with isotropy of space, I can't tell?
And why exactly as an example of this association between angular momentum and isotropy of space they give the example of the invariance of a closed physical system under rotation?
I mean, from what I've learned, the angular momentum conservation is true for a system over which  no torque is present. And "closed system" I believe it means that no forces act on it.

Angular momentum is conserved in the case of a central force. So, the idea that no forces and no torques should acto on the system is false.

You are right about the no force part, but in a central potential, the torque is zero, so that should hold,no?

The problem with assigning "conservative properties" to potentials lies with the idea that the potential is absolute and that it does not experience a "back reaction". It's essentially just a willful neglect of the forces that the system exerts on the sources of the potential. A properly formulated physical potential is always momentum and angular momentum conserving. Newton's third law already says so. The problem only appears when we write unphysical potentials of the form V(r) for a single particle down. A correctly treated single particle is always free and can not change its motion.

In the equation $\hat R{}^\dagger\hat{\mathcal H}\hat R=\hat{\mathcal H}$, substitute $\hat R=\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\vartheta\hat L_z}$ and linearise to get $[\hat{\mathcal H},\hat L_z]=0$, and then repeat for the other rotation axes. This holds for all angles, not just the linearised limit, but it is sufficient to prove this relation in the infinitesimal limit.

Your edit makes no sense. The rotational symmetry will be broken by you adding a random other new thing to it. Our aim is to extract facts from the rotational symmetry, so you are definitely way too wrong.
